# Hibernate: receive generated ID from a callable custom insert

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, identity

I have an entity class with

```
@Entity
@SQLInsert(callable = true, sql = "{ call sp_InsertEntity(?, ?, ?) }")
public class Entity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "entity_id")
  private int entityId;
...
}
```

sp_InsertEntity does standard INSERT and returns @@IDENTITY.
But after session.save(entity) entityId value remains 0.

How to force Hibernate using the returned value or an output parameter or @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY() for the generated ID initialization?

Comment: I've found solution in setting         <property name="jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">false</property>

Answer (score 2):

Maybe to clarify it a bit for others that run into the same problem - when you use  `<property name="jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">false</property>`, hibernate will not automatically generate its SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() after your procedure (which obviously doesn't work in the first place, because that select isn't in the same scope as the insert), hence you have to manually add the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() after the insert within the stored procedure.

Writing your insert stored procedures in this way will also make them compatible with how Entity Framework handles things, which is a nice plus.